# cannot upload images to mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to upload images to mysql server using php.
I have created html and sql connectivity but the image upload shows error.
I cant upload the image, it shows error of valid image i.e. you must upload jpeg,bmp,gif; and read/write in directory.

Can any1 help me solving this problem
the php file is

```
    <?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

// Check to see if the type of file uploaded is a valid image type
function valid($file)
{
    // This is an array that holds all the valid image MIME types
    $valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif");

    //echo $file['type'];
    if (in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

// Build our target path full string.  This is where the file will be moved do
// i.e.  images/picture.jpg
$TARGET_PATH = "image/";
$TARGET_PATH = $TARGET_PATH . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);

$pimage = $_FILES['image']['name'];

// Check to make sure that our file is actually an image
    // You check the file type instead of the extension because the extension can easily   be faked
    if (!valid($pimage))
    {
   $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = array('You must upload a jpeg, gif, or bmp');
   header("Location: admin.php");
   exit;
     }

// Here we check to see if a file with that name already exists
   // You could get past filename problems by appending a timestamp to the filename and then      continuing
   if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
   {
 $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = array('A file with that name already exists');
 header("Location: admin.php");
     exit;
   }

 // Lets attempt to move the file from its temporary directory to its new home
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH))
   {
  // NOTE: This is where a lot of people make mistakes.
  // We are *not* putting the image into the database; we are putting a reference to the     file's location on the server
   $sql = "insert into people (p_category, p_name, p_quantity, p_desc, p_image) values        ('$pcategory', '$pname','$pquantity','pdesc', '" . $pimage['name'] . "')";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
    //Check whether the query was successful or not
      if($result) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = array('Product added');;
    $_SESSION['MSG_FLAG'] = 0;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: admin.php");
    exit();
     }else {
    die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());
        }
       }
       else
       {
     // A common cause of file moving failures is because of bad permissions on the     directory attempting to be written to
     // Make sure you chmod the directory to be writeable
     $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = array('Could not upload file.  Check read/write persmissions on the directory');
      header("Location: admin.php");
      exit;
       }
?>
```

Comment: looks like your code is trying to upload image to the disk but your question says you're trying to upload it to MySQL?

Comment: What's the error?  Are you writing to a database or to the file system?  The error you describe suggests the latter.

Comment: "We are *not* putting the image into the database; we are putting a reference to the file's location on the server"... so we're not uploading images to MySQL using PHP - we're storing their temporary file names, which may or may not be unique.....

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right.

Comment: Nowhere in your code to actually check if the upload actually succeeded. You're just assuming everything worked perfectly. Bad idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you are passing the image type in the line `if (!valid($pimage))`
But in the valid() function you are again trying to get the type of image `$file['type']`.

What George said should also work, but since you are making variables for the image type `$ptype` and name `$pimage`, you can use them itself.

So the changes should be `$file['type']` becomes `$file` and `$file['type']` & in the insert query `$pimage['name']` becomes `$pimage`

I'm sure this solves it, Bahua ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
$pimage = $_FILES['image']['name'];
```

should be

```
$pimage = $_FILES['image'];
```

You probably missed this because your code is quite inconsistent - sometimes you use `$pimage`, while elsewhere you reference the `$_FILES` array directly. This makes it harder to maintain should the file field's name change. You could also type hint the `valid()` function to make PHP complain if `$file` isn't an array:

```
function valid(array $file) { ... }
```

What level of error reporting do you have set? It would highlight errors like trying to access undefined array keys.